# mysqldump generates a blank file via PHP system()

Tags: php, system, mysql

Before you say there are other questions like this, but none of the answers I've seen worked, so I'm making a fresh question.

I'm trying to use `mysqldump` via `system()` with this command:

```
$backup_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/website/acp/backup/';
$backup_name = $backup_path . $dbname . '.backup.' . date('l.dS.F.Y.g.iA') . '.sql';

$command = 'mysqldump ' . $dbname . ' -u ' . $dbuser . ' -p' . $dbpasswd . ' > ' . $backup_name;

system($command, $returned);

print_r($returned);
```

`$returned` outputs `127` and a blank file with a size of zero KB is located in the backup folder, now when I echo `$command` and then enter it into Terminal, it works perfectly and generates a full backup of the database. This is the part I don't understand, why is it not working well in the `system()` call but in Terminal it works just fine?

Comment: Does the specified user account have the required "file" privilege?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when running mysqldump you are required to enter the password, even if you specify it with -p

This should be helpful : http://www.techiecorner.com/1619/how-to-setup-mysqldump-without-password-in-cronjob/

Answer (score 0):

Your problem could well be that you don't have permission to write to the backups directory.

If you run the code:

```
$backup_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/website/acp/backup/';
file_put_contents("{$backup_path}test-file.txt", "test data");
```

Does a file appear in the backup directory?

If not you need to modify the permissions of the directory so that the webserver user can write to it. `chmod 777` is the easy solution but will leave the permissions wide open.

Answer (score 0):

I have to disagree with Andrei's answer above.

The following works on a number of shared hosting companies:

```
$command = 'mysqldump --opt --host='.$host.' --user='.$mysql_username.' --password=\''.$mysql_password.'\' '.$dbname.' > \''.$filename.'\'';
exec($command);
```

Careful if you have white space anywhere in your arguments (file names, passwords, etc) that you use quotes. In PHP you might need to use back slashes, like I did above, when quoting. Preceeding or trailing spaces are usually a bad idea, but I've encountered a client where this turned out to be the reason for an empty, 0 bytes mysqldump file. Quoting fixed the problem. You might also need to shell escape the arguments.

The following two lines are quite different:

```
-password='password  ' db_name > 'my file.sql'
-password=password   db_name > my file.sql
```

Note that the second one also has two spaces at the end of the password, but even HTML may ignore it.

I should probably mention for the noobs... make sure you can manually connect with the settings before looking for reasons it is not working, e.g.
- make sure the host is correct, e.g. localhost or yourdb.website.com
- make sure the username and password work